# Не получается настроить логирование для телеграмм бота

Tags: java, spring

После создания logback.xml логи перестали писаться в консоль а бот перестал запускаться вовсе

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.testbot</groupId>
    <artifactId>testbot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testbot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.7.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Вот logback

```
<configuration>

    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="/var/log/org.testbot/testbot/app.log"/>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/org.testbot/testbot/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 60 days to keep -->
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.testbot.testbot" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </root>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

```
SLF4J(W): Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J(W): Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@147e2ae7]
SLF4J(W): Found provider [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@448c8166]
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

```
SLF4J(I): Actual provider is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@147e2ae7]
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.LoggerConverter@77cf3f8b - failed to parse integer string [1.] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1."
```

Даже после полного удаления зависимостей появляются вот эти ошибки

```
SLF4J(W): Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J(W): Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@147e2ae7]
SLF4J(W): Found provider [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@448c8166]
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J(I): Actual provider is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@147e2ae7]
```

```
февр. 03, 2024 11:47:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
февр. 03, 2024 11:47:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
февр. 03, 2024 11:47:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
февр. 03, 2024 11:47:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
февр. 03, 2024 11:47:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по сообщению об ошибке, похоже, что проблема вызвана опечаткой в шаблоне `%c{1.}`:

```xml
<pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
```

Согласно [документации](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html), длина должна быть представлена как **целое число**, т.е. `%c{1}`

> `c{length}`
> Outputs the name of the logger at the origin of the logging event.
> This conversion word takes an integer as its first and only option...